# Rails 5 apply default url options for non-JSON resources only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added `config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true }` to my `application.rb` which works great for all of my helpers, etc. however I'd like to avoid adding a trailing slash to my JSON resources. Desired behaviour:
`some/page.json`
instead of the current:
`some/page/.json/`

Comment: See if this works, config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true, format: 'html' }

Comment: May be you can also use exclude like this config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true, exclude:  [/^json$/] }

Comment: I would vote up @Ucpuzz answer if i could .

Comment: @Ucpuzz neither of those work, `format: html` gives all urls an .html extension and the json option adds `exclude%5B%5D=%28%3F-mix%3A%5Ejson%24%29>` to them